# Is the function sqlite3_changes thread safe?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 database in a multi threaded application. (The library is properly compiled and set to threadsafe mode).

After executing a statement of kind `insert into table1 select from table2`, I want to check whether the statement inserted some rows in table1 or not.

In both cases the execution of `sqlite3_step()` returns `SQLITE_DONE`.

Looking in the description of sqlite3_changes() function, which looks exactly what I need, there are two bothering problems in its description:

1. It works not on the statement, but on the database connection, that I use in all threads.
2. According to the function description it seems to be not thread-safe:

> If a separate thread makes changes on the same database connection while sqlite3_changes() is running then the value returned is unpredictable and not meaningful.

So, is this function thread safe or not? Is there a way to get the number of the inserted rows on statement basis, not on connection basis?

Comment: Using the same connection from multiple threads will not crash the database, but it will muck up your transactions. Why don't you use separate locking, or multiple connections?

Comment: @CL. Well, I don't know what you actually mean. In my experience it behaves very well with multiply threads.